# Android software that shoots a range of at least +/– 5.0 EV for the bracketed set

Tags: hdr, bracketing, android, android-app

I'm using a Galaxy S7 Edge phone and the Android app called Camera FV-5 to take bracketed exposures for HDR photography. That software takes a bracketed set of +/- 2.0 EV maximum. I found out that I need at least +/– 5.0 EV for the bracketed set to get good HDR images.

Does anyone know of an app that gives me at least +/– 5.0 EV for the bracketed set?

Comment: +/-5 EV is a _huge_ difference. What are you shooting that you decided/fount out that you need that much dynamic range? If you try to HDR that much range, the result will likely look too unnatural.

Comment: @scottbb It depends a bit on the difference between raw and 8-bit jpeg. An 8-bit jpeg is only good for about 7 stops of DR, so a +/-2 EV set is only good for about 11 stops. A +/-5 stop set of jpegs would still only get you to about 17 stops DR. On the other hand, a *single* raw file can be good for about 12-13 stops. That gives a +/-2 EV set of raw files 16-17 stops of DR, about the same as a +/-5 EV set of jpegs. Only a +/-5 EV set of *raw* files would extend to about 22-23 stops.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The +/– 5.0 EV came from an HDR book I'm reading. So that means +/– 2.0 EV will get good results? Is it better to have several stops vs 3 stops? My phone can do 7 stops within the +/– 2.0 EV EV range.

Comment: I'm also saving raw images.

Comment: If you are saving RAW images, ±2 stops should be enough, assuming you're bracketing around an appropriate middle level that gives you decent shadow and highlight detail in your set. That said, if you want more than ±2EV, you could adjust your exposure compensation up/down, keeping your phone on a tripod, and shoot multiple bracketed sets of ±2EV, getting rid of any duplicate exposures. That could extend the range, when needed, but of course would require a fairly static scene.

Answer (score 4):

**[Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera)** can be configured to take up to 5 images at up to ±3 stops for exposure bracketing.

**[Camera ZOOM FX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.cameraZoom)** can be configured to save all images taken by its HDR mode (don't know how many or at what EV stops).

Both can save DNG files via Camera2 API.

Comment: thanks for the software names. I will try them to see if they give me better results. I've already tried camera fv-5 but the dng files ended up with a lot of noise on low light shots. Maybe those will give better results. I use the aurora hdr software to process the shots. I get excellent results when using my DSLR with the same brackets from the camera.

Comment: I doubt DNG files will differ between programs because, in principle, they are supposed to contain raw sensor data.

Answer (score 1):

[HedgeCam 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.caddish_hedgehog.hedgecam2) can be configured to bracket ±4 EV.